# jQuery .scroll() events for the body/window/html/document

Tags: jquery, mobile, cross-browser, scroll

I need a cross-browser way of binding to the scroll event for the browser's native scrollbar.

$("html, body") seems to work for firefox, while $(window) seems to work for IE.

Is there a better way to use the correct version rather than trial and error? I also would like to detect mobile scrolling, if possible.

Comment: $(window).scroll() works on all browsers. I just [tried this out myself](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/kJt9z/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `$(window).scroll()` works with IE (and it works with firefox and Chrome too) i think you should use it